# Add event-listeners to label found by Tensorflow model

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

Is there a way to make the labels found by the Tensorflow model clickable in a UI?

I want to be able to take a picture of an image on my phone, when the model has analysed and returned the labels, I would like to click on any of the labels and carry out some other action in the UI.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it has nothing to do with tensorflow. Based on the platform you developing the UI, this feature can handle differently. In most programming languages it is named as [Event Handling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_(computing)).

Here is a sudo-code:

```
prediction = model(input) # inference by tensorflow
chnage_ui(prediction) # change UI accordingly
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. The event handling will be done using javascript in a PWA.

Comment: I hope it helps. If you think this is the answer of the question then you can accept it in order to help others get benefit from both question and answer.